# Wrong file in vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:64 when i install magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3.4, ubuntu, gd2

Please help me.

It's displayed below error when I have cloned and installed Magento 2.

[image]

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, but you most probably have a theme declared that does not have a proper image set. You can try to disable all the non-core themes and try again. and try to install your theme after everything works. to disable the theme edit the file `app/design/frontend/{theme-name}/registration.php`. Rename it to something else. (if the theme is located in the app/design folder). If it was installed by composer, then remove it from composer.json.

Answer (score 9):

i was trying to install `Magento 2.3.5-p1` on `WINDOWS 7 (32 bit)` (yes it's out of date) and i run into the same error.

as per [this thread](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/28055), the error seems to be related to Windows platforms and the workaround was to add `!file_exists($filename)` condition to the `if` statement.

- 1 Open `vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` file
- 2 Find `validateURLScheme` function at `line 96`
- 3 Append `!file_exists($filename)` condition to `if` statement :

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
  {
      $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
      $url = parse_url($filename);

      
      // Here !
      if ($url && 
          isset($url['scheme']) && 
          !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && 
          !file_exists($filename)
      ) {

          return false;
      }

      return true;
  }
```

Anyway, this tweak worked for me till an official fix since the issue is still Open.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: This seems to be very serious issue for windows.

Comment: in fact, as per the official Mgento's devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html
Magento is NOT supported on Windows and Mac !

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into this problem for my `Magento 2.3.5-p2` in wamp server on Windows 10.

It looks like it is windows related problem only (I am yet to confirm that), I had to add `strlen($url['scheme']) > 1` in the function of `vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` file:

So the final function looks like this:

```
/**
 * Checks for invalid URL schema if it exists
 *
 * @param string $filename
 * @return bool
 */
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
    $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
    $url = parse_url($filename);
    if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && strlen($url['scheme']) > 1 && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.

I changed vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php file, Line 63 to:

if (!$filename || filesize($filename) === 0) {

After this I can install magento.

Or you can change url to 127.0.0.1, maybe it is ok.

Hope I can help you.

Comment: thank you so much!