# Image not uploaded wrong file

Tags: magento2, admin

I am trying to upload image in backend but i am getting below error in admin.

I am not handling to debug php code and only familiar with html/css + basics js and many modules are already installed in default system  so don't know where the exactly the issue is might be **fileuploader.php** file.

[image]

So if anyone has idea about patch work or quick fix then it would be helpful.I am in windows system. I don't want to fix it in proper way but i need some patch so i can later revert that patch.|

I already tried deleting pub/media gave permission to them but it seems not an issue.

I have checked in console and got below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have temporarily fixed it by changing in magento core Gd2.php file line no 96 by adding one more if condition

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
    {
        $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
        $url = parse_url($filename);
        if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

`vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php` as suggested in this answer

[Wrong file in vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php:64 when i install magento 2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311639/wrong-file-in-vendor-magento-framework-image-adapter-gd2-php64-when-i-install-m)

I don't know if it is proper way or not but at-least it works and now i am able to upload image in the backend in my windows system.

Comment: Thanks buddy worked for me :)